# Syntax error when create enum type using knex.raw()

Tags: knex.js

I want to create an enum type using `knex.raw()` method, here is my `migrate` code:

```js
import * as Knex from 'knex';
import { ChannelEnum } from '../types';

exports.up = function(knex: Knex): Promise<any> {
  return Promise.all([
    knex.schema
      .createTable('channel', (t: Knex.TableBuilder) => {
        t.increments();
        const enumOptions: Knex.EnumOptions = {
          useNative: true,
          enumName: 'channel_nme_b'
        };
        t.enum('channel_nme_a', [ChannelEnum.FACEBOOK, ChannelEnum.GOOGLE, ChannelEnum.INSTAGRAM]);
        t.enum('channel_nme_b', [ChannelEnum.FACEBOOK, ChannelEnum.GOOGLE, ChannelEnum.INSTAGRAM], enumOptions);
      })
      .then(() => {
        return knex.raw(`create type "channel_nme_c" as enum (?,?,?);`, [
          ChannelEnum.FACEBOOK,
          ChannelEnum.GOOGLE,
          ChannelEnum.INSTAGRAM
        ]);
      })
      .then(() => {
        return knex.raw(`alter table "channel" add column if not exists channel_nme_c channel_nme_c;`);
      })
  ]);
};
```

But got an error:

```sh
{ method: 'raw',
  sql: 'create type "channel_nme_c" as enum (?,?,?);',
  bindings: [ 'FACEBOOK', 'GOOGLE', 'INSTAGRAM' ],
  options: {},
  __knexQueryUid: 'f8fdf6f3-50d1-4b2e-afbc-8d9e971471fb' }
migration file "20181211102654_db.ts" failed
migration failed with error: create type "channel_nme_c" as enum ($1,$2,$3); - syntax error at or near "$1"
{ method: 'update',
  options: {},
  timeout: false,
  cancelOnTimeout: false,
  bindings: [ 0 ],
  __knexQueryUid: '38a05697-3446-432a-a3f5-5d0ca7940049',
  sql: 'update "knex_migrations_lock" set "is_locked" = ?',
  returning: undefined }
error: syntax error at or near "$1"
    at Connection.parseE (/Users/ldu020/workspace/nodejs-pg-knex-samples/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:554:11)
    at Connection.parseMessage (/Users/ldu020/workspace/nodejs-pg-knex-samples/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:379:19)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/ldu020/workspace/nodejs-pg-knex-samples/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:119:22)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:208:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:597:20)
```

It seems that `bindings` of raw is not correct, but don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably postgresql doesn't allow to use value bindings for enum values. You need to interpolate those values to the SQL string like:

```
return knex.raw(`create type "channel_nme_c" as enum ('${ChannelEnum.FACEBOOK}', '${ChannelEnum.GOOGLE}', '${ChannelEnum.INSTAGRAM}')`);
```

Comment: So, `Knex.js` based on `pg`. It does not do any work for this?  Just pass raw sql and bindings to `query` method of `pg` directly?

Comment: Knex cannot possibly know that what SQL that you have written to `raw` actually means. So if those `?` for bindings has been put to invalid places for generating postgresql compatible SQL then it is the database who throws an error, not knex. To be able to do that in knex side we would have to include complete SQL parsers for all the SQL dialects, which is way out of scope for the library.

Answer (score 0):

I do more tests for create an enum type using `pg` driver. It seems `pg` driver does not support value bindings for this case.

```js
const sql = `
  create type "channel_nme_d" as enum ($1, $2, $3);
`;
const res = await client.query(sql, [ChannelEnum.FACEBOOK, ChannelEnum.GOOGLE, ChannelEnum.INSTAGRAM]);
```

Above code will throw an error: `error: syntax error at or near "$1"`

Below code will work fine.

```js
const sql = `
  create type "channel_nme_e" as enum ('${ChannelEnum.FACEBOOK}','${ChannelEnum.GOOGLE}','${
  ChannelEnum.INSTAGRAM
}');
`;
const res = await client.query(sql);
```

Check enum types:

```
nodejs-pg-knex-samples-# \dT
          List of data types
 Schema |     Name      | Description
--------+---------------+-------------
 public | channel_nme_b |
 public | channel_nme_c |
 public | channel_nme_e |
(3 rows)
```

It seems `knex.raw(sql, bindings)` just pass raw sql and bindings to `query` method of `pg` directly.

Comment: Nicely copied my answer... You should still fix minor detail how `knex` passes `raw` SQL and parameters to 'pg' driver. `Knex` doesn't pass them there directly. It first changes `?`, `??` and other bindings in SQL string to a format that is supported by `pg` driver (by adding correct identifier quoting and changing to binding format to `$1`,`$2`,... etc.).